# How to run ElastAlert on windows 12

Tags: python, python-3.x, elastalert, elastalert2

Below is the stack trace I got when I ran the example rule.

```
C:\Windows\system32>python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --rule example_fre
quency.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.p
y", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.p
y", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-pa
ckages\elastalert-0.2.4-py3.6.egg\elastalert\elastalert.py", line 31, in <module
>
    from .config import load_conf
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-pa
ckages\elastalert-0.2.4-py3.6.egg\elastalert\config.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import loaders
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-pa
ckages\elastalert-0.2.4-py3.6.egg\elastalert\loaders.py", line 9, in <module>
    import jsonschema
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-pa
ckages\jsonschema-4.4.0-py3.6.egg\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema._format import (
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-pa
ckages\jsonschema-4.4.0-py3.6.egg\jsonschema\_format.py", line 1
    from __future__ import annotations
    ^
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

Steps I followed to setup ElastAlert is as below:

- git clone https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert.git
- pip install "setuptools>=11.3"
- python setup.py install
  But when I ran the example rule it is giving error.
  I am running this on WindowsServer 12 R2

Answer (score 0):

Importing annotations from future (`from __future__ import annotations`) was added in python 3.7.

You will need to either install a new version of Python or create a virtual environment with a new version of Python to get the code to run.

Comment: I have added python 3.10.1 but again getting some errors as below
```
    from . import ruletypes
  File "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-p
ackages\elastalert-0.2.4-py3.10.egg\elastalert\ruletypes.py", line 6, in <module
>
    from blist import sortedlist
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blist'
```